# Colpitts' oscillator

Tags: rf, analog

Edit 1. The question got taken down so I made edits. Here is the colpitts oscillator circuit:
[image]

I encountered a problem where once the component gets small enough (I want a frequency in the hundreds of MHz range), the oscillation stops. I would like a frequency in 433 MHz.

Can someone please explain why this happens and how I can fix this?

Comment: Why haven't you posted a schematic?

Answer (score 2):

> However, I encountered a problem where once the component gets small enough (I want a frequency in the hundreds of MHz range), the oscillation stops?

The loop gain becomes less than 1, at the intended oscillating frequency. The Barkhausen criteria state that an oscillator will not oscillate unless at some frequency the loop gain is at least 1, and the feedback has a net phase shift of 180 degrees (or 0 degrees depending upon your conventions) at that frequency.

The loop gain typically falls because the gain of the transistor falls as the frequency rises. However, it is not always the transistor that is at fault. If the feedback ratio is too low, the loop gain can fall below 1 in that case as well. The feedback ratio might fall due to the ratio between the inductance and capacitance becoming too high, making the impedance of your tank network too high.

It may also be the case that the parasitic reactance in the wires, traces, breadboard, and in the components themselves have made it so the phase shift of the feedback network is never 180 degrees (or zero degrees) except above the frequency at which the transistor is able to amplify. That is, improved layout of your circuit, and the use of components with less parasitics may allow your circuit to oscillate at your desired frequency.